# Problom With VBA code throw an “user defined type not defined” error

Tags: excel, vba

I cannot figure out why the following code is throwing a compile error with the message "user defined type not defined". It is highlighting Set fso = FileSystemObject

```
Sub S()     
Dim fso As FileSystemObject
    Dim ts As TextStream
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim myCell As Range

    Set fso = FileSystemObject

    For i = 0 To TotalColumnNumber
       ' last argument, True, says to create the text file if it doesnt exist, which is
       ' good for us in this case
       Set ts = fso.OpenTextFile("column_" & i, ForWriting, True)

       ' set mycell to the first cell in the ith column
       Set myCell = SheetName.Cells(1, i)

       ' continue looping down the column until you reach a blank cell
       ' writing each cell value as you go
       Do Until myCell.Value = ""
           ts.writeline myCell.Value
           Set myCell = myCell.Offset(1, 0)
       Loop

       ts.Close
    Next

    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing


    End Sub
```

thanks

Comment: Move the line ***Sub S()*** to the top of your code.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent now  Sub S() is highlighting :(

Comment: Try `Set fso = New FileSystemObject`

Comment: https://trumpexcel.com/vba-filesystemobject/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code has <strike>many</strike> several problems:

1. You need to set a Reference

[image]

2. use:  Set fso = `New FileSystemObject`
3. establish values for your variables **before** you use them; this includes `TotalColumnNumber`, `SheetName`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Are you referencing the correct namespaces in Tools/References?